# What determines the # of pins of a cmos Imaging sensor?

Tags: cmos, pins, pinout, floating-pin

Why do some cmos Imaging sensors have 48 pins and others 36 and some 34...e.c.t? I'm new to these sensors and I don't really understand the connectivity differences.

Comment: What sort of sensor? Image sensor? Humidity sensor? Pressure? All can be CMOS, please provide details.

Answer (score 1):

The design of the sensor and the interface really.  Some are a parallel interface and could be 8,10,12 bit etc.  It might include hsync and vsync or they might use embedded sync codes.  Or it could be a serial interface and have only on lane or four or eight.

The configuration interface could be spi or i2c.  One might have more powers and grounds than another etc.

So really it's sensor dependent although the interfaces are somewhat similar.